# How to show newly inserted mysql data into laravel view automatically without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I have an `ajax request` that is showing returning data and displaying same data again and again in loop. Here is my output-[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLq3F.png) But i want to `show only newly inserted data with old data`. Now can anyone please help me with that issue please ? I am providing my script bellow.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var info = 0; //Set id to 0 so you will get all records on page load.
   var request = function () {
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{!!URL::to("matchview")!!}',
    data:{'id':info},
    success:function(data){
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        console.log(data);
        $('#a').append('<td>'+data[i].match_name+'</td>');
      }
    },
    error:function(){

    }
  });
};
 setInterval(request, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: console the data variable if you have right data then you can apply loop.

Comment: already did it.you can see it in my script and i also provide output result . It is not in the correct way. it is showing same data again and again

Comment: you are using two .each loop what's that for? console on each step you will get what you are doing wrong. Without looking at data format I can not suggest you any thing.

Comment: Ok..i am trying with one loop.Then i will inform you

Comment: one console outside out loop and second console inside of loop. that will help you to identify the data you want.

Comment: checked it .it showing error . Now i changed my script .but it is showing same kind of result.

Comment: please add `console.log(data)` before `loop start` and Please share your data. that you are print in console before loop and after loop.

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]
view:342 (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {match_name: "BD vs INDIA"}1: {match_name: "Ferdous Bhuiyan"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
view:344 (2) [{…}, {…}]

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for this problem.It works for me.My new script is given bellow--

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var info = 0; //Set id to 0 so you will get all records on page load.
    var request = function () {
    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'{!!URL::to("matchview")!!}',
    data:{'id':info},
    success:function(data){
    $('#tbody').empty();
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        console.log(data);
        $('#tbody').append('<tr data-expanded="true" id="a"> 
    <td>'+data[i].match_name+'</td></tr>');
      }
      },
      error:function(){

      }
     });
     };
      setInterval(request, 1000);
     });
  </script>
```